# Shifting an LFSR loop in O(1) time?

Tags: random, finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm looking for a way to mathematically combine two concepts: [LFSRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR), and [Barrel Shifters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter)

I'm looking for a way, in O(1) time, to shift an LFSR loop a given number of shifts.

What I'm hoping to find is a simple process where I have the current state of the LFSR and the number of times I want to shift from that state as parameters to a quick/easy process.

At first I just thought about looking at all the taps, then moving the taps over by 1 and looking at them again, finding the shift in bit each time and appending it onto the end but of course this isn't O(1) and it gets complicated if I want to shift so many times that a tap would "slide off" the original LFSR state.

I may be in the wrong place to ask this because I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically. Although any incite into how it's possible (or why it's impossible) would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure such a way exists...

Comment: me either, but I can hope

Comment: @Dilip: Please see the discussion [on this meta answer and comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4000/622).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I deleted the lfsr tag, and so it can stay on the list of deleted tags on meta

Answer (score 2):

The successive contents of a (binary) maximal-length linear feedback shift register with $n$ stages can be interpreted as the elements 
$\ldots, \alpha^{i-1}, \alpha^i, \alpha^{i+1}, \ldots,$ of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$
(where $\alpha$ is a primitive element in the field) expressed in the 
*dual-polynomial* basis (see the answers and comments on
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84942/15941)).
So what you are asking is,

> Given the *current state* $\alpha^i$ and an integer $j$, compute
>   the state $\alpha^{i+j}$ as quickly as possible (preferably in $O(1)$ 
>   time).

This would require either

- exponentiation (compute $\alpha^j$) followed
  by multiplication (to find $\alpha^i \times \alpha^j$)

or

- a *discrete logarithm*
  computation (find $i = \log_{\alpha}(\alpha^i)$ followed by addition
  ($i+j$) and exponentiation.

This fleshes out @YuvalFilmus's hint
that a simple method may not exist.  Of course, if $n$ is not too
large, and the set of values of $j$ that you are interested in is
not too large, *table look-up* would be the way to solve the problem
instead of barrel shifters.  If $j$ can be only two or three
values, you can implement the transformation $\alpha^i \to \alpha^{i+j}$
using Exclusive-OR trees with feedback going not just to the last
stage of the LFSR but to several stages.