# Clarification on rings of polynomials / Galois fields

Tags: terminology, finite-fields

I need some clarification about what the following thing is called (it's commonly used to describe [linear-feedback shift registers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/generator-and-char-polynomial-for-a-binary-galois-field-produced-by-an-external)), and what a good computer program identifier would be that describes it.

---

The set $p(x)$ of polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in GF(2), modulo a characteristic polynomial $p_c(x)$ with coefficients in GF(2).

---

I'm not a mathematician, so I always get this wrong. Is it a ring of polynomials over the field GF(2)? How do you work the characteristic polynomial into the terminology? ($p_c(x)$ may or may not be irreducible; I work with both cases.)

And what would be a good computer program identifier to represent the set of polynomials for a specific characteristic polynomial $p_c(x)$?  `GF2PolynomialRing`? `GF2PolynomialModRing`?

Answer (score 1):

If the polynomial is irreducible of degree $n$, it's what mathematicians would call the [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of order $2^n$ and what people in other areas might call a Galois field $\text{GF}(2^n)$. `GF(2, n)` looks good to me. It is a cool and surprising fact that this finite field does not depend on the choice of polynomial, as long as it is irreducible of degree $n$, which is why it's not mentioned in the notation.

(For the purpose of describing LFSRs you need a [stronger condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)) than irreducibility.)

Comment: OK, thanks. The objects I work have characteristic polynomials that are not always irreducible (e.g. not always a maximum-length LFSR). For the identifier I can only use alphanumeric characters, so I can't use `GF(2,n)` but I could use `GaloisField`. (`GF` would be frowned upon by software engineers for being too terse.)

Comment: @Jason: if the polynomial isn't irreducible then what you get is not a field. You could describe it as a quotient ring (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) of the ring of polynomials.

Comment: ah! Thanks, sounds like I should use something like `GF2QuotientRing` then. I appreciate it -- when I read formal mathematical documents I get lost in the thicket of terminology.

Comment: edit your answer to include the info about quotient rings + I'll accept.

Comment: So would it be accurate to call it the quotient ring GF(2)/p(x), where p(x) is the characteristic polynomial?