# Why Fibonacci LFSR random number generation works?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

If I use primitive polynomial of GF($2^m$) in Fibonacci LFSR, it is generating all m-length binary combinations. But, I cannot understand why this should happen. I am not getting any mathematical explanation regarding this problem. Can somebody give me some reasoning?

Comment: I can explain about [Galois_LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Galois_LFSRs) . In that wiki example, "next" polynomial to 0xACE1 (i.e. $p(x)=x^{15}+x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^5+x^4+x^2+1$) is $xp(x) \bmod{g(x)}$ with $g(x)$ being $x^{16}+x^5+x^3+x^2+1$ primitive polynomial of the root of $x^{65535}-1$. I don't see how it's connected to Fibonacci LFSR, do you?

Comment: Dilip Sarwate explains this in his comments to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85108/11619). A single iteration of a Fibonacci LFSR represents multiplication by the coset of $x$ as does the Galois LFSR, but using a dual basis.